# Flickering select element with CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm trying to color a select/combo box with CSS, but I seem to get a horrible white 'flicker' every time I press the button to drop down the list.

For a fraction of a second it displays the list with a white background, and then changes it to black.

Anyone know of a way around this?

```html
<body style="background:#202020;">
<select name="year" style="background:black;color:#505050;">
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
```

It doesn't do it on IE, seems to be only on Chrome (on Windows 10).

An Example of it happening here: https://youtu.be/ewhumjUOwK8

Comment: Using Chrome on Windows 10 here. No flickering but no color change either.

Comment: Strange, are you using the most recent version of Chrome? Happens to me on 2 diff PCs... You can see it on a vid capture here: https://youtu.be/ewhumjUOwK8

Comment: I've seen it too now. It happens completely at random.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed the last click on the vid worked ok but the others didn't. I'm guessing its some kind of Chrome bug maybe. I'll log a report with them and see what they say. Was hoping it there was some kind of workaround though. Thanks for our conformation though that it also happens to you.

Answer (score 0):

i cannot replicate the problem ( neither in Chrome nor in Firefox ) . but you should be more specific when styling .

1. for example , select has a default `background-color` . so instead of `background` use `background-color` , like below :

```html
<body style="background:#202020;">
<select name="year" style="background-color:black;color:#505050;">
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
```

2. if you can use css, ( or you can write inline styles to all the options )  give to the options the same background-color as to the select . that might solve it

```css
div select[name="year"] {
  background-color:black;
}
div select[name="year"] option {
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<body style="background:#202020;">
<div>


<select name="year" style="color:#505050;">
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
</div>
```

3. if you can use CSS , be more specific about the select and it's path , for example if the select is inside a div use this ( also use the name attribute to be more specific about the select ) . i repeat, be as specific as you can when selecting the `select` in CSS ( if you can use CSS )

```css
div select[name="year"] {
 background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<body style="background:#202020;">
<div>


<select name="year" style="color:#505050;">
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
</div>
```

4. the least recommended option is to use `!important`

```html
<body style="background:#202020;">
<div>


<select name="year" style="background-color:black!important;color:#505050;">
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't help. That was just 'quick' css/html to show the problem. Even your 'correct' examples cause the flicker for me. Not sure why its not happening to some. It happens on 2 PC's I've tested it on :(

Comment: then i guess is just a browser related problem that you cannot change